# How to delete a overload function from overload resolution?

Tags: c++, c++17, overloading, overload-resolution

Say I have a class `STest` and I want it to be able to implicitly cast to `char const*` but not `bool`.

```
struct STest {
    operator char const*() const& { return "abc"; }
    operator bool() const& = delete;
};

void bar(bool) {}

void foo(bool) {}
void foo(char const*) {}
```

This implementation works as expected (error) when calling `bar(STest{})`. But it doesn't work for `foo(STest{})` because deleted function is also considered in overload resolution and it complains ambiguity. Is there a way to workaround this which means `bar(STest{})` raises an error and `foo(STest{})` calls `foo(char const*)`?

Comment: Personally I would just get rid of the implicit casting behavior and make things explicit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a conversion operator template, and constrain it with SFINAE.

```
struct STest {
    template<typename T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<char const*, T>::value, int> = 0>
    operator T() const& { return "abc"; }
};
```

Instead of having two overloads participating and causing an error when the wrong one is chosen, this will instead deduce the target type from context, and will then decide if the overload should be removed from overload resolution at all. With a single overload there won't be ambiguity.

Comment: The const lvalue [ref qualifier](https://crascit.com/2015/11/29/member-function-overloading-choices-you-didnt-know-you-had/) is a nice touch!